# Making an intearctive graph in R

Tags: r

Is there anyway to make a graph in R that has some sort of I/O pop up box that would let the user check/uncheck criteria to change the plot shown?  For example, if I had the following plot:

[image]

Would there be a way for a sidebar or pop up window for the user to check or uncheck so that one of the lines disappears from the graph?

Comment: Apparently I can't post the image until I have 10 rep points.

Comment: Have you looked much into [Shiny](http://www.rstudio.com/shiny/)?

Comment: No I have not...I am not super R savvy

Comment: Check out google vis with R.

Comment: Can somebody provide me with example code?

Comment: @Stat Man, can't speak for Google vis, but probably the most efficient way to learn enough about Shiny/R to at least know what further questions to ask is to go through their tutorial-- http://rstudio.github.io/shiny/tutorial/ Shouldn't take longer than an hour or two (not counting possible one-time installation headaches, but that's how these things go).

Answer (score 0):

The `tkexamp` function in the TeachingDemos package helps create interactive plots like this using a tk window, the help page has several examples.